# Android Battery Report generated

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I have a very simple application that listens to WiFi event (broadcastreceiver manifest) and occasionally start a WiFi scan.

Now i am getting report back from user that if they look at battery report my application is standing at 20%.

Now seeing that that's about the only thing the application does why is the usage so high.

How is this report generated. Does it also include battery usage of the services and feature you use like WiFi in your application percentage.

Or am  just doing something wrong.

thanks

Comment: Have you holding any wake lock? or doing while loop infinitely?

Comment: Nope nothing like that.